# Trying to remove large amounts of text from pandas series with a list

Tags: python, performance, list, pandas, nlp

My problem is basically as follows. I have a pandas dataframe, with a column which contains fairly large amounts of text (generally 20 to 200 words). This dataframe is about 600k rows. On top of that I have a list of words, which is about 150k items long, which need to be filtered out of the strings in the dataframe. I am currently using this method to do this:

```
for word in uncommon_words:
    reports['Report_Clean_Filtered'] = reports['Report_Clean'].str.replace(word, '')
```

Where uncommon_words is the list of words and reports is the dataframe.

My estimation is that this will take around 27 hours on my machine. Is there a better (or at least faster) way to do this? I have a very open mind! :)

Answer (score 2):

Join the list of `uncommon_words` with the or operator `|` and replace it all at once

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=['hello bye one two', "hello", "bye 1"]))
                   a
0  hello bye one two
1              hello
2              bye 1

uncommon_words = ['hello', 'bye']

df.a.str.replace('|'.join(uncommon_words), '')

0      one two
1             
2            1
```

Comment: This seems to work, but is still incredibly slow, do you think it may just not be possibly to do fast? I'm actually starting to think this might be a big data problem.

Comment: @Daannnn How long is this expected to take? Are you going to have to perform this task frequently or is it just a one off? These are some questions you'd want to ask yourself before you consider it a big data problem. If so, ask another question on stack overflow stating that you have tried my answer and someone might now some faster (potentially numpy/cython) approaches to this problem. Hope that helps